# php __soapCall how to get attribute

Tags: php, soap

How to get attribute with __soapCall?

I think have following WSDL endpoint structure:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Names">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="NameTypes" type="tns:ArrayOfNameType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfNameType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="NameType" nillable="true" type="tns:NameType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="NameType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="Id" type="xsd:unsignedInt" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and with soap call

```
$vem = $client->__soapCall("GetNames", array(), null, $header);
```

I get following results as a content of the $vem variable:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [NameTypes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [NameType] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => first name
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => second name
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => third name
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Is there any way to get also that Id attribute value defined in the NameType block in the WSDL? Or what is the purpose of that Id Attribute?

Thank you in advance!